# Считывание данных YUV с камеры ANDROID и перевод в RGB

Tags: android, камера

Добрый день! Кто сталкивался с вопросом считывания матрицы `YUV` с камеры Андроида и переводом в `RGB` формат? Подскажите, как именно считать саму матрицу и правильно перевести в `RGB`. Спасибо.

Comment: Raw с камеры взять нельзя, если я правильно понял, что тебе надо

Answer (score 1):

Зачем?
Камера отдает в JPEG данные, если ее попросить:

```
        Camera.Parameters parameters = c.getParameters();
        parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG); 
        c.setParameters(parameters);
```

И не нужно ничего конвертировать. с - естесно экземпляр Camera.

Ну или если хочется его, то [там](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) есть формулы.

Comment: спасибо, но это не подходит))) Дело в том, что мне нужно в потоке брать массив байт - сырые данные камеры, когда камера находится в состоянии "открыта".  Известно, что сырые данные камеры - это YUV, для последующего наложения фильтра черно-белого не на картинку а в реальном времени необходимо знать RGB.
Однако вопрос снят. я уже реализовала данный функционал, всем спасибо за участие

Comment: любые данные кроме RAW имеют уже потери, так что в данном случае сырые - это не сырые, а обработанные ПО камеры данные с матрицы. И смысл сей пляски, когда можно брать JPEG сразу, который в RGB. Преобразуете каряво - потеряете данные. Прикольно че:)

Comment: Jpeg это не RGB, это YCbCr...

Answer (score 0):

[Converting YUV->RGB(Image processing)->YUV during onPreviewFrame in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325861/converting-yuv-rgbimage-processing-yuv-during-onpreviewframe-in-android).

Comment: спасибо, только там немного не то что нужно было. У них испоьзовался их класс ConfigManager для получения размеров. Я уже сделала, спасибо за помощь!